# Load random image from static folder that is linked with JSON file

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, flask

I'm trying to create a riddle game in Python based on [rebuses](http://brainden.com/picture-rebus-puzzles.htm).

I have a JSON file containing the filename and the answer. I'm trying to create the game logic which is essentially loading a random image from the static folder and have it linked to the JSON file and the answer. Correct answers can progress you to the next one.

I've tried various methods I've found online of loading random images from the static folder and random JSON objects independent of each other but I can't figure out how to load them and have them associated with one other.

**json code:**

```
{
"questions": [
    {
        "imageUrl": "/static/Beg-2-Differ.png"
        "imagename": "Beg-2-Differ.png",
        "answer": "beg to differ"
    },
    {
        "imageUrl": "/static/bote.png"
        "imagename": "Beginning-Of-The_End.png",
        "answer": "Beginning of the end"
    },
]
}
```

If I could get pointed in the right direction on how to write the python code to solve this it would help me greatly!

Comment: So once you've loaded a random image from the static folder, are you basically asking how you would then locate the corresponding object in the `questions` list?

Comment: @WillKeeling yes that's exactly it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've loaded a random image from the static folder, then you should already have the filename for that image. Based on that, you can iterate the list of question objects and look for the object with a `imageUrl` with that filename.

You've not shown the code that you're using to load a random image, but assuming it looks something similar to this:

```py
import random
import os

static_folder = '/path/to/static'
random_image = random.choice(os.listdir(static_folder))

with open(os.path.join(static_folder, random_image), 'rb') as image_file:
    # Do something with the loaded image_file
```

You could then load the corresponding question object like this:

```
import json
import os

with open('/path/to/questions.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

    for question in data['questions']:
        if os.path.basename(question['imageUrl']) == random_image:
            # We've found the question object for the image
```

This uses the filename of the `imageUrl` for the comparison which I assume corresponds to the actual filename on disk (rather than `imagename` which seems to correspond to a display name).